# Data quality Numeric Columns only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to setup a data quality check for numeric columns in a dataframe. I want to run the describe() to produce stats on each numeric columns. How can I filter out other columns to produce stats.   See line of code I'm using.

df1 = pandas.read_csv("D:/dc_Project/loans.csv")
print(df1.describe(include=sorted(df1)))

Comment: `df[df.columns[df.dtypes!='object']]`?

Comment: by default `describe` only uses numeric columns..`include: None (default) : The result will include all numeric columns.`

Comment: Tried answer got error date data types and 'O'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the following from a teammate:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pandas.read_csv("D:/dc_Project/loans.csv")
df2=df1.select_dtypes(include=np.number)